# Shrinking the Code

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I've got some java code that is used for my games NPCs to move arround.

Those are obviously in an 1d array.

```
public void route11() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random number = new Random();
    int random = number.nextInt(2);

    if(random ==1)
        hunters[1].x = hunters[1].x -1;
    else
        hunters[1].y = hunters[1].y -1;  
}

public void Update() {
    route11();
    route2();
    route3();
    route4();
    route5();
}
```

Methods route2, route3, ..., route5 look pretty much the same, the only thing that changes is the value of the array to correspond with a different hunter.

Could this code be "shrinked"? Im pretty sure my lecturer will be happy to minus my mark for such a messy and very much anti-OO code.

Also, all my collision/score code looks something like this, and it works for individual hunters:

```
if(hunters[i].x==0 && hunters[i].y == 0){
    hunters[i].x = 11;
    hunters[i].y = 11;
    Player.score = Player.score + 1;
}
```

Comment: please share the code for a couple of the methods

Comment: what happens in route2/3/4/5? code can't be consolidated if each separate chunk does something completely different.

Comment: @Marc B `the only thing that changes is the value of the array to correspond with a different hunter.` I think that makes it pretty clear that he is copy pasting the code and just changing the hunter that it affects.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has nothing to do with OOP design. This is just about learning to use the tools available to write less redundant and more manageable code. If you utilize a for loop in your update and pass each individual hunter then this becomes much more condensed.

I will note that there are some unrelated OOP issues that you would do well to correct.

- Hunter's members such as X and Y should not be exposed publicly, utilize getters/setters
- The same goes for the Player's score member/field

  ```
  public void update()
  {
     for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         route(hunters[i]);
         collisionAndScoring(hunters[i]);
     }
  }

  public void route(Hunter hunter)
  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random number = new Random();
      int random = number.nextInt(2);
      if(random == 1)
      {
         hunters.x--;
      }
      else
      {
         hunter.y--;
      }
   }

   public void collisionAndScoring(Hunter hunter)
   {
       if (hunter.x == 0 && hunter.y == 0) //You should define constants for these to give them more meaning
       {
           hunter.x = 11; //another opportunity for a constant
           hunter.y = 11; //another opportunity for a constant
           Player.score++; 
       }
    }
  ```

Comment: Nice refactoring! Could add some explanation to him as well?

Comment: @jsalonen Just did =P I wanted to make sure I beat anyone to the punch first haha.

Comment: @MatthewCox That's called "Fastest Gun in the West" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/147335 and is defined as: A problem identified as a side-effect of sorting votes by descending score where first-posted answers are quickly up-voted, trumping vote opportunities for people who sit down and answer a question in a long, thorough way.

Comment: @glowcoder Point well taken. I would do well to more thoroughly answer the question the first time. Clearly, it has an affect while the answer is still in thoroughness-limbo.